# 2 ordered pairs are equal if and only if the 1st sets in each are equal, and the 2nd sets in each are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c,d \rangle$ if and only if $(a=c) \land (b=d)$

Does this mean that if there are 2 distinct pairs of equal sets joined by and, they must be ordered?

If so, does this mean the 1st pair of sets in the and statement has to come 1st in the ordered pair?

If so, why does the 1st equal set come first and not the second?

It's my understanding that $a \land b = b \land a$, which the above statement is making me reconsider.

Comment: I don't understand the notation in your first sentence.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If a pair is "ordered" that means we have distinguished the first and second elements.  Thus the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are different (well, assuming $a\neq b$).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Are you talking about ordered pairs defined e.g. as Kuratowski pairs $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (or perhaps Russel pairs $(a,b):=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ or a couple of other similar attempts to define ordered pairs in terms of set theory)?

Comment: How do you escape carrots? Like less than and greater than? I'm talking about Kuratowski's definition. I'm reading Set Theory by Zaring and he gives the definition that got hidden in 5.2)6).

Comment: Escaping carrots is not hard.  They do not run very fast.  I don't know about escaping carets.  A backslash does not work.  You get less than by \lt and greater than by \gt

Comment: Haha, the dollar sign surrounding the caret on both sides worked

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an **ordered** pair is designed to be ordered: the first (left) and second (right) element play different roles. If $a \neq b$ then $\langle a,b\rangle \neq \langle b,a \rangle$. The clause just defines a criterion to check for *equality* of two pairs: how to check that pairs are equal.

So $(a=c) \land (b=d)$ also implies $\langle b,a\rangle = \langle d,c\rangle$, as we have the same criterion to check in both cases.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is if (a=c)^(b=d), do a and c need to be first in the ordered pair? That's what it looks like to me. If not, how do you determine which comes first and is my understanding of "if and only if" wrong?

Comment: @AlGJohnston in the statement $(a=c) \land (b=d)$ the order of the $=$-clauses does not matter. The order is in the pair: you see which are left half members and which are right half members.

Comment: So if and only if doesn't imply that the right implies the left?

Comment: @AlGJohnston Of course it does, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Then if  $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c,d \rangle$ if and only if $(a=c) \land (b=d)$ how come a and c come first?

Comment: $(a=c) \land (b=d)$ also implies $\langle b,a\rangle = \langle d,c\rangle$ of course.

Comment: How can both be true?

Comment: @AlGJohnston like I said $\langle a,b\rangle = \langle c,d\rangle \iff \langle b,a\rangle = \langle d,c\rangle $. The equivalence of equalities says nothing about pairs from one statement being equal to one in the other.